# URL Rewriting to Privately Access Files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to build a simple website which is going to let users upload files, and privately share them with other designated users. The problem is: I don't want anyone to be able to type in the url for a file to be able to get to it (then anyone could see it).

I decided to try using `.htaccess` to prevent direct url access, however, I cannot figure out how to access the file myself. All of the uploaded files are going to go into a **subfolder** called **"restricted"**.

My `".htaccess"` file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} !^.*key=SECRET.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^restricted/(.*)$ showfile.php?file=$1
```

My "showfile.php" file:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('[...]/restricted/'.$_GET['file'].'?key=SECRET');
?>
```

However, when I open `"restricted/test.txt"` or some other file in the restricted folder, it successfully redirects to `"showfile.php?file=test.txt"`, however, I get a php error:

> Warning: file_get_contents([...]/restricted/test.txt?key=SECRET)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in [...]/showfile.php on line 10

It seems like even though the query string contains `"key=SECRET"`, it is still trying to redirect.

What I want: I want it to redirect on direct URL access, but that I can access it through the php page it's redirected to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the file as an HTTP resource instead of direct disk access (like in your question), you can do the following:

Code in .htaccess (placed the "nonpublic_test" folder):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/restricted/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*key=SECRET.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=403,L]
```

Then in your showfile.php:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://www.domain.name.here/restricted/'.$_GET['file'].'?key=SECRET');
?>
```

This will prevent any access to the restricted folder and its contents but still allow your showfile.php script to access the file inside that folder and output it.

Comment: I tried that, and when I go to the url I don't see it (good), when I go to the url with "?key=SECRET" appended, I do see it (good), but when I use the file_get_contents, I still don't see it (bad)? Is it something with how the file_get_contents function works?

Comment: Never mind, I just realized I'm supposed to put file_get_contents('http://[...]'). I didn't have the 'http' before. It works now.

Comment: True, I had copied that from your question. I edited the answer now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be better off to move `restricted` folder a level above site root and have your PHP code in `showfile.php` like this:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents('/path/to/restricted/'.$_GET['file']);
?>
```

With rule simply as:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^restricted/(.*)$ showfile.php?file=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but when you say to move the restricted folder to a level above the site root, what exactly is the "site root"? would that be the "public_html" folder, or the "mywebsite.com" folder, or something else?

Comment: Yes that would be your `DocumentRoot` folder i.e. `public_html` wherever your main .htaccess reside.

Comment: Then how would I reference that file (e.g. test.txt) from the showfile.php? That is, what would my '/path/to/restricted' be (for example)? Because there is no url to refer to it if it is not in public_html, right?

Comment: You can still access files inside `restricted` folder outside `DocumentRoot` using filesystem path of the file since you're not accessing it using `http://` route.